# Variable in all views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have two different controllers called Bank and Change in my Rails project. In my Change controller I have got the variable: `@dollar = 3.3`.

I can fetch dollar in the view of change with `<= @dollar %>`, but it doesnt work in the view of bank. How can I access `@dollar` in a diffrent controller/view?

Comment: For us to give a good answer, you should explain *why* you want to do this.

Comment: May be setting up a method in ApplicationController and call it in any controller action.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible ways of doing this:

- add '@dollar = 3.3' in the bank controller as well
- make the the dollar and bank controllers children of a dollarBankController and set '@dollar = 3.3' in this parent controller